# The normalization of the momentum eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, normalization

If the momentum eigenfunction is this
[image: 1]

but it is not normalized, and if we apply the normalization condition which is this
[image: 2]

will you get infinity instead of 1?

Comment: Yes. And that tells you that these eigenstates are not physically realizable states; there is no such thing as a free particle with a definite momentum even in principle.